# copyURLToFile behavior in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, apache

I'm using `copyURLToFile` to download a file from url.

When I use it sequentially, in a loop, about 74% of the iterations sucsseds.
But when I use it in multithreading and there are 100 concurrently running Threads, it drops down to below 5%.
Interestingly enough, when i debug the program, it get back to 74% sucsses and even higher.

Every unsuccessful attempt is caused by an exception thrown:

`java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:`

My question is whether FileUtils uses some limited resource which cause a race condition, or any other reason it fails in significantly higher rate in multithreaded environment.

I have checked [the documentation of copyURLToFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File,%20int,%20int)), but there is no refernce there to this issue.
I have also checked [the source code of copyURLToFile](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#FileUtils.copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL%2Cjava.io.File%29)), but couldn't spot any thing to give a hint of why those exceptions are thrown.

```
public void doDownload () {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        // Get the page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(YouTubeConvertor);
        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        final List<HtmlForm> form = page1.getForms();

        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.get(0).getInputByName(InputName);
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.get(0).getInputByValue(InputValue);

        // Change the value of the text field
        textField.setValueAttribute(this.link);

        // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
        HtmlElement down =  page2.getHtmlElementById(FileElement);
        String name = down.getAttribute(HrefElement);
        URL linkUrl = new URL(name);
        File f = new File (Dir , this.saveName + Mp3Ending);
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(linkUrl, f);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Some form of error happened!   " + ex.toString());
        // timeout based on attempts and time elapsed
        if (times++ < 10 && TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert
                (System.nanoTime()-this.startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) < 60) {
            doDownload ();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post your code, particularly where you're getting your URLs from.

Comment: I added the code. The URL's are fixed, and they all correct, i checked it in debug-mode.

Comment: Edited, the no value exception was thrown becuase of other problem.